# PHP Form page array not continuing to response page

Tags: php, arrays, response

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Newspaper</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>How much does it cost</h1>
        <p>This form will allow you to find out how much a newspaper costs</p>
        <form name="choose" action="response.php" method="POST">
            <p>Which newspaper are you interested in? 
            <?php
                $newspaper = array("The Guardian", "The Times", "The Sun", "The Mirror");

                echo '<select name="newspaper">';
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($newspaper); $i++) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' ;
                    echo $newspaper[$i] ;
                    echo '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
            ?> 
            </p>
            <p>Press to get the price<input type="submit" name="continue" value="continue" /></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

RESPONSE PAGE

```
<?php
    $newspaper=$_POST['newspaper'];
    $newspaperNames= array ("The Guardian", "The Times", "The Sun", "The Mirror");
    $newspaperPrice= array('0.9','1','0.5','0.5');
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Newspaper</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>How much does it cost</h1>
        <?php
            print "<p> Your Newspaper is " .$newspaper. "</p>";

            print "<p>Your  Newspaper is " .$newspaper. "</p>";
            if ($newspaper== "The Guardian") {
                print "<p>Your newspaper cost " .$newspaperPrice[0]."</p>";
            } else
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hi there kind of a noob here with php. having an issue where for some reason I cannot get the selected array to continue to the response page where it will show what was selected from the previous array and if that newspaper was selected the correct price from the 2nd array will appear?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You use the position of the newspaper as a key in the option value. That means you can use it like this:

```
<?php
    $newspaper = $_POST['newspaper'];
    $newspaperNames= array ("The Guardian", "The Times", "The Sun", "The Mirror");
    $newspaperPrice= array('0.9','1','0.5','0.5');
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Newspaper</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>How much does it cost</h1>
        <?php
            echo "<p>Your  Newspaper is " .$newspaperNames[$newspaper]. "</p>";
            echo "<p>Your newspaper cost " .$newspaperPrice[$newspaper]."</p>"; 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

- Note: please check if the input is posted (`isset()`)

Comment: For debugging you can use print_r($_POST)

Comment: True. I think it is better to use a multidimensional array instead of two arrays. But that is more depending on the way this script will be used and the "style" of the creator of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `print`s with `echo`, like yarwest said.

```php
<?php
echo "<p>Your  Newspaper is $newspaper</p>";
if ($newspaper == "The Guardian") {
    echo "<p>Your newspaper cost {$newspaperPrice[0]}</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To print something in PHP you'd have to use `echo` (like you are doing in the form). You can also use variables inside strings with double quotes.
For example:
`echo "<p> Your Newspaper is $newspaper</p>"`

On top of that, you have an else statement without a condition or body.

Fix this and I am sure you will be closer to something working.

Answer (score 1):

Put your array in another file and `include` it from both:

```
<?php
$newspapers = [
    [
        'name' => 'The Guardian',
        'price' => '0.9',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'The Times',
        'price' => '1',
    ],
    ...
]
```

In your selection page

```
<p>Which newspaper are you interested in?
<select name="newspaper">
<?php
include 'papers.inc';# or whatever
foreach ($newspapers as $index => $newspaper) {
    echo '<option value="', $index, '">', $newspaper['name'], '</option>';
}
?>
...
```

In your response page

```
<?php
include 'papers.inc';
$index = $_POST['newspaper'];
?>
...
<p>Your newspaper is <?php echo $newspapers[$index]['name'];?>, which costs <?php echo $newspapers[$index]['price'];?>
```